# Passing visualforce value to another visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 2 Visualforce Pages and each pages has an `<apex:inputtext/>`.What I want is passing The value of the first inputtext  into another Visualforce inputtext . Please Help Me Experts.

Thankyou

Comment: Can you post the related code snippets ? Specially how you navigate from first page into the second page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PAGE 1** - if you see below page, we have an inputtext with a value which is bind to the controller. We have a button on this page, clicking on which you will be navigated to next page.

```
<apex:page controller="Controller1" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputtext value="{!inputText1}"  />  
        <br />
        <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!GoToPage2}" reRender="result"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**CONTROLLER 1** - this controller has inputText1 declared with get,set. It contains the method that passes this text in url appended in 'att' (assuming 'pagetwo' is name of your second page)

```
public class Controller1{
    public String inputText1 {get;set;}
    public Controller1(){
    }
    public pageReference GoToPage2(){
        PageReference pf = new PageReference('/apex/pagetwo?att='+inputText1);
        return pf;
    }
}
```

**PAGE 2 -** has inputText2 which is again bind with controller and value is displayed in VF page.

```
<apex:page controller="Controller2" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputtext value="{!inputText2}"  />  
        <br />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**CONTROLLER 2-** if you observe this, all we are doing is getting the 'att' from URL in constructor and assigning to inputText2

```
public class Controller2{
    public String inputText2 {get;set;}
    public Controller2(){
        inputText2 = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('att');
    }
}
```

Thus you ll observe that inputText1 is passed from page1 to page2 and displayed there. This is pretty generic example that I can think of!

Answer (score 0):

pass the value you enter in VF page 1 to VF page 2, using url. You need to set the value of input in url as parameter.

See the code :

```
public String valueofInputtext {get; set;}
public PageReference callPageVF2() {
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('\apex\VFpage2?Inputvalue ='+valueofInputtext);
acctPage.setRedirect(true);
return acctPage;
}
```

In the controller of your Vfpage2 get the value as

```
 ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Inputvalue');
```

or you can get the same value in your VF page direct by

```
{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Inputvalue}
```

This my help you out.